# Zurbs Foundation for MACOS?

Tags: macos, frameworks, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to download the complete foundation frameworks package on macOS?

I'm taking a course on webdev and the instructor using windows has a few package options when they choose to download it ( Essential, Custom, Complete, Sass, etc.)

but when I click on it, Im only able to download the sites package, which doesnt seem to include all the necessary files for the course.

I'm new to all this, sorry if its a pretty lame questions, if its a operating system issue, ill live, but thought id throw it out here before I gave up completely.

Answer (score 0):

Zurb Foundation has gone through a number of changes over the last few years, the main one being that it is no longer maintained by Zurb themselves. More on that can be found here:

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/11767

and here:

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/12191

My assumption is that the group of maintainers now running the project have reduced the number of download options with the main one being the main compiled css package that contains all the Foundation elements.

Comment: Thanks ! I didnt even think to look it on github, I'll start there next time ! Thanks again.